# in Kdb, how do I assign a list of symbols each to a list of values

Tags: function, dictionary, variable-assignment, kdb

For example, I want to pass a dictionary with 10 pairs into a function to bypass the 8 valence limit. I then want the keys of the dictionary each to be assigned as a local variable to be assigned to their value and use that as the parameters for my function. Alternatively, is there a better way to pull this off?

Comment: I agree with Anton - why not just use the variables from the dictionary via lookups? You don't need to have them as named local variables

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid there is no way to functionally assign value to local scope variable. E.g.

```
{eval parse "a: 10";}1b
```

creates global variable `a`.

You may fix some scope name, e.g. `.l`, keep variables there and clear scope before function return, e.g.:

```
{
  eval each (:),'flip (`$".l.",/:string key x;value x);
  r: .l.a + .l.b + .l.c;
  delete from `.l;
  r
}`a`b`c!1 2 3
```

But getting values directly from input dictionary (like `` x[`a] ``) seems easier and clearer approach.

---

[`apply`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/) helps to simplify invoking other functions, using dictionary values as parameters. This may be what you are looking for. E.g.

```
{
  f: {x+y+z};
  f . x`a`b`c
}`a`b`c!1 2 3
```